# Is in-memory session store implemented in Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I try to create in-memory session store with Kafka Streams, but I can't find such implementation. I've found `RocksDBSessionStore` (which works pretty well) and `InMemoryKeyValueStore`, but there isn't any `InMemorySessionStore`.

Comment: Your observation is correct. It's a missing feature: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4730

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax - Have you used InMemoryKeyValueStore? I am trying to use it a local store, so that I can hold on to a peice of information, that I can access later on in the transform() phase in the stream processing pipeline.

Comment: Yes. I have use it. Not sure what your question is? Check out the docs: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#defining-and-creating-a-state-store

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax KAFKA-4730 is not for InMemorySessionStore, but for InMemoryWindowStore

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8029